Autodesk Platform Services: how to convert 2D layers to PDF or bitmaps
We are currently using Autodesk.Forge's .NET library in conjunction with svf-utils command line to extract a GLTF mesh from any model translated to SVF on Autodesk Platform Service via the Model-Derivative API. And this is working very fine for the 3D models.
We now want to do the same for 2D objects/layers (e.g. floor map in AutoCAD or Revit projects) and extract either a PDF or a bitmap (PNG/JPEG) with arbitrary resolution (we will convert large bitmaps to tiled bitmaps if necessary).
What is the best solution to extract a PDF or bitmap from a SVF or any models stored in a APS bucket?
I found tat the SVF does include 1 F2D file for each 2D layer, but this F2D does not seem to be a valid Fusion file anyway; and we still need to convert it to PDF or bitmap; or even understand the internal 2D primitives describing the layer.
The final goal if to display the 2D layers like we already display the 3D meshes in our custom app which cannot embed the APS-Viewer due to too many custom objects to render.
Thanks :-)
Stephane
